# TextBoxWatermarkExtender not showing text

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

There's this very simple bit a code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbVipNumber" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="tbweVipNumber" runat="server" 
    WatermarkText="VIP number" TargetControlID="txbVipNumber"
    WatermarkCssClass="watermark">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

And there is no watermark in my textbox when i look at the page.

How come it doesn't work?

EDIT: added css

```
.watermark {
    color:Gray;
    font-size:smaller;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a scriptmanager on the page? What is your watermark CSS look like?

Comment: Yes there is a scriptmanager tag, and i'll add the css on the post

Comment: Could you post an example page URL to see? Also, you could use Firebug or Google Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the element and see if there are any styles that hinder the text to display.

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks for remembering me about Firebug and the javascript error console. *Feels stupid right now*. And so i found that there were some javascript error, one in perticular that said that i should use "ToolkitScriptManager" instead of "ScriptManager". Solved everything. Thanks again

Comment: @Shadowxvii you can post your solution here so maybe some other see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. Thanks for remembering me about Firebug and the javascript error console. Feels stupid right now. And so i found that there were some javascript error, one in perticular that said that i should use "ToolkitScriptManager" instead of "ScriptManager". Solved everything. Thanks again

P.S. It's sad there is no way to mark a question as answered if there is no answer. That would be usefull for self-answered questions.

Comment: SO actually [encourages answering your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Marking a question as answered without an answer is logically just not possible